# How do i roll mutiples dices in one command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot, i already made a dice rolling systen, but I want to improve it. I want to roll multiple dices at once, like Avrae can do.

```
@client.command(aliases=['r', 'dado', 'dice'])
async def roll(ctx, dados='', numero=20, conta='', ficha=''):
  rolagem = random.randint(1,int(numero))
  if conta == '':
        total = (int(rolagem))
  elif conta == '+':
         total = (int(rolagem) + int(ficha))
  elif conta == '-':
         total = (int(rolagem) - int(ficha))
  elif conta == 'x':
         total = (int(rolagem) * int(ficha))
  elif conta == '/':
         total = (int(rolagem) / int(ficha))
  if ficha == '':
          ficha = ''
  if total < 0:
          total = '1'
  if total == 0:
          total == '1'
  if rolagem == 20:
          rolagem = '**20**'
  if rolagem == 1:
          rolagem = '**1**'
  await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}  \n**Resultado**: D{numero} ({rolagem}) {conta} {ficha}\n**Total**: {total}')
```

So, the command should work like: (prefix)r (number of dices to roll) (dice), and show the results like: (number of dices rolled):(dices results)(sum of the dices result)
For exemple: -r 5 d20; Results for 5 D20:(1, 5, 8, 16, 20) (sum).
I want to know how I shoul do it

Comment: It's pretty simple. you have 1 case covered, now you need to solve for `n` cases. Consider wrapping your code with a loop (e.g. a for loop running `n` times), adding the result to a list of results, then returning the sum of that list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a roll function I wrote, modified to use strings like you did:

```
import random


def roll(n='1', d='20', a='+', m='0'):
    res = []
    for i in range(int(n)):
        res.append(random.randint(1, int(d)))

    roll_modified = sum(res)
    if a == '+' or a == '-' or a == '*' or a == '/':
        roll_modified = eval('{}{}{}'.format(roll_modified, a, int(m)))

    if roll_modified < 1:
        roll_modified = 1

    return roll_modified, res
```

It uses `eval` to apply the modifiers, so use with caution. I check the value of the operator and use `int()` on the number to ensure it is a safe expression.

Use it like this:

```
roll_modified, res = roll('3', '20', '-', '2')
```

- `roll_modified` is the result after applying sum and modifiers.
- `res` is a list of all the original rolls

You could then print your results with:

```
res_str = ["**{}**".format(x) if x == 20 or x == 1 else str(x) for x in res]
print(roll_modified, "[{}]".format(", ".join(res_str)))
```

will output:

```
36 [14, 4, **20**]
```

Comment: it didn't work... idk how to add anithing from there to my code

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?